# Reading Project Tree from Adobe After Effect file (.aep File)

Tags: javascript, python, c++, node.js, adobe

[image: after effect]

I need to read all the information, specially composition tree from ".aep" file programmatically, if its be in JSON format will be much better.

This job will be done automatically after someone uploads a "aep" file from a dashboard on a website.

Since my backend is Django, I prefer python but I'm open for any other solution that can be done **automatically**.

Comment: You can use ExtendedScript for this.Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit is you best bet for this. It's normally in javascript. Will allow you to read everything in the project, and change things as well.

Comment: https://github.com/boltframe/aftereffects-aep-parser Just a quick google search for "aep parsers" resulted in this as the first search result. If you're looking to parse it by hand, this would probably be a good resource to follow with, as there seems to not be any official documentation available (As far as i could find)

Answer (score 2):

[python-lottie](https://gitlab.com/mattbas/python-lottie/-/tree/master/lib/lottie/parsers/aep) has some rudimentary AEP parsing support, you can also implement your own parser using the [documentation on lottie docs](https://lottiefiles.github.io/lottie-docs/aep).

Comment: As I understood from avatars, you wrote it :), I will try to implement this this week  thanks for helping.